# Finding $\displaystyle{\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}}\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y}\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{x^2y}{x^3}|\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{x^2y}{x^2}|=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|y|=0$$

But the answer is there is no limit, where did I get it wrong?

Comment: You cannot approach the origin via the path $\;y=-x^3\;$ and thus the limit cannot exist...

Comment: @DonAntonio So there must be something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Indeed so. For example, the first inequality is unjustified, and if you had begun with absolute value then it'd be completely wrong. Also the second one is wrong: when $\;x\to0\;$  and $\;x\;$ close enough to zero (say, $\;|x|<1\;$)  , then $\;|x|^3<|x|^2 \;$ ...\

Comment: @DonAntonio the path $y=-x^3$ is not a good path to study the limit. We have to choose a path that is locally  in the domain of the function for $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.

Comment: @Ixion **Precisely** that path is what shows the limit cannot exist as, *by definition*, if it exists it must be **the same** no matter how we approach the limit point of the variable(s) . It is the same with one or several variables. And in this case we cannot approach the limit point $\;(0,0)\;$ from one particular "direction", or in one particular way.

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks for your answer, but I think that if I use your definition, all the limits that have a function with a denominator (that is 0 over a path) don't exist.

Comment: @Ixion and you'd be right, see my comment below.

Comment: @Ixion  I'm not sure what you mean, but remember that in the definition of limit we do not require the existence of the function in the limit point: we don't even care what happens to the function at that very point, if anything at all... **but we do require** the function is *defined* in some (open, of course) neighborhood of the limit point...and that does **not** happen in this case.

Comment: @Ixion, take this one-dimensional analog to make sense of it:  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \sqrt x$ does not exist because $x$ can't approach $0$ from the left.  (We can say $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt x = 0$ because $x \to 0^+$, i.e., $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, is ok).  Similarly, in two dimensions, $(x,y)$ can't approach $(0,0)$ on the path $y=-x^3$ for $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2y}{x^3+y}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that $(0,0)$ can be approached from different directions. For example, if $(x,y) = (\epsilon, \epsilon),$ and $\epsilon \to 0,$ we have $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2 y}{x^3 + y} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{\epsilon^3}{\epsilon^3 + \epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2 + 1} = 0,$$ but if $(x,y) = (\epsilon, -\epsilon^3)$ your denominator vanishes and the limit is undefined.

The first inequality in your answer need not be satisfied.

Comment: "The first inequality in your answer need not be satisfied" why?

Comment: what if $x$ is negative?

Comment: Furthermore, the limit of $x^2y /x^3$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$ is not $0$ either, it is again undefined, as you can move to the origin along different directions (compare $x=y$, or $x=y^2$).

Comment: You can't take $(x,y)=(\epsilon, -\epsilon^3)$

Comment: @Ixion You can take the pair $(x,y)$ to be whatever you like. The fact that the expression is undefined there is indicative of the fact that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ixion You're right: he can't...and that's what shows the limit cannot exist!

Comment: @onamoonlessnight: $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x y)}{x y}$ exists, but if we consider the paths $(x,y)=(0, y)$ or $(x,y)=(x, 0)$ the function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ixion Not quite. The whole point of taking limits is to see what a function might be defined as, if you wished to make it continuous, at a point where you cannot evaluate it directly. Now in two dimensions a limit is said to exist if and only if it exists along every curve approaching your point of interest. Considering functions that have line singularities, such as your example, is different then. The fact that $\sin(x)/x$ exists as $x\to 0$ is not the same as saying that the *2-dimensonal* limit exists when you replace $x$ with $xy$.

Comment: A function with a line singularity (which admittedly is also the OP's function), by definition, cannot have a well defined *2-dimensional* limit at a point on the line of singularities.

Comment: @onamoonlessnight "Now in two dimensions a limit is said to exist if and only if it exists along every curve approaching your point of interest." This is imprecise in my opinion. The chosen path must be locally on the domain of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Ixion here's a more precise definition to satisfy you: $f\to l $ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall (x,y) \in B_{\delta}(0,0)$ $|f(x,y) - l| < \epsilon$. Notice the second $\forall$.

Comment: @Ixion The example you gave above is usually given as $$\;f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin xy}{xy},&xy\neq0\\{}\\\text{whatever},&xy=0\end{cases}$$ Thus, this function **is defined** in some neighborhood of $\;(0,0)\;$ ...

Comment: @onamoonlessnight. This is my definition of limit: let $$f\ : \ \mbox{dom}(f)\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$$ We say that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0, y_0)}f(x,y)=L\in\mathbb{R}$$ if and only if $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ such that if $B_{\delta}(x_0,y_0)\cap\mbox{dom}(f)$ then $$|f(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon$$. If $(x,y)\notin\mbox{dom}(f)$ then $f(x,y)$ doesn't have sense.

Comment: @Ixion Where did you take that definition from, please?

Comment: @DonAntonio: this is the definition my teacher gave me :(

Comment: @DonAntonio: sorry, I have to edit my definition but I can't. I missed a piece. "such that if $(x,y)\in B_{\delta}(x_0,y_0)\cap \mbox{dom}(f)$ then $|f(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon$... Sorry.

Comment: I guess the whole discussion pivots around whether you require that your function be defined in a neighbourhood of the point. The standard definition certainly has this requirement, but perhaps the course you're following uses a slightly different one. Do check though, that the intersection with $dom(f)$ is not taken just to ensure that you are in a small enough neighbourhood of the limit point, i.e. to avoid far-away singularities.

Comment: @onamoonlessnight: now I'm really confused :(

Comment: @Ixion Sorry, perhaps that was not very well phrased. You could have a situation where you don't have a line singularity, but your function nonetheless has an isolated singularity arbitrarily close to, but away from the limit point, that you would like to avoid by restricting to the domain of definition. Perhaps this is the situation your teacher was trying to include. However, in this case the singularities will necessarily accumulate at the limit point.

Comment: I think I will open a question about this, but probably it will be blocked :\

Answer (score 2):

The limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2 y}{x^3+y}$$ doesn't exists.

If we take the line $(x,y)=(0, y)$ than the limit becomes $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{0\cdot y}{0+y}=0$$

So, if the limit exists its value is $0$, but if we consider the path $(x,y)=(x, -x^3+x^5)$ the limit becomes $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2(-x^3+x^5)}{x^3+(-x^3+x^5)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^5+x^7}{x^3-x^3+x^5}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^5}{x^5}=-1\ne 0$$

Comment: Please, explain the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: Someone probably didn't follow your second equality in that last line.

Answer (score 0):

Your first inequality doesn't hold necessarily. For example if $x>0$ and $0\leqslant - y \leqslant x^3$ .

You should try with two different curves (specific ones) in order to have 2 different limits.

If you need some clue (after putting some effort), just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The limit exist only when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ in every direction.  In particular, if we approach $(0,0)$ along the line $x=0$, then the limit, if it exists, must be equal to $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{0\cdot y}{0+y}$.  However, this is an indeterminate form...  On the other hand, if we approach $(0,0)$ another way, say along $y=x$, then the expression becomes $\lim_{x\to 0}
\frac{x^3}{x^3+x}=0$.  Hence, the limit cannot exist.